# Where can I find Geany's default global configuration files?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, ide, geany

I was trying to install the [Vibrant Ink](http://code.google.com/p/geany-vibrant-ink-theme/) Geany theme and ended up with it not working. As far as I understand, the filetype definitions weren't working or something. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAXb9.jpg).

I messed around with a little bit and accidentally moved my backup when restoring it instead of copying it, did stuff, deleted it, intending to restore a backup that I'd just deleted, and then proceed to screw up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

How can I get Vibrant Ink to work, or where do I find Geany's global configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I have found is this: https://github.com/geany/geany/tree/master/data, which is a very partial answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Geany is generating file *geany.conf* and such based on default values inside the source code, if not existent.

Filetypes, etc. are stored at `/usr/local/share/geany` if you have installed Geany on your own from sources into defaults.

Answer (score 0):

It could different in other version but in **Puppy Linux** you will find it under

/usr/share/geany/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).